# Is there a way to accept inbound SMS from contacts not in your database?

Tags: sms

I have a client who has a service they'd like to merge into CiviSMS.  Strangers (i.e. not in the database) can send a text with a keyword; ideally it should create a contact with their phone number.  Using reports/Views, staff will review new incoming messages and respond to the contacts accordingly.

Is that possible with CiviSMS?

Answer (score 3):

Jaap Jansma at CiviCoop has developed two extensions that do this for us. It is connected to a Norwegian sms provider, but the code is available on github.

He used a trick... To automatically create a contact with no name, but only email(as Civi requirements for creating a contact). A contact with cell phone number 123456789 would then get an email like this: 123456789@mobile.sms

This is again easy to search for or make a report for back office staff to go through. (Email adresses containing @mobile.sms)

[Norwegian sms provider PSWincom](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.pswincom)

[Sms autoreply](https://github.com/CiviCooP/org.civicoop.smsautoreply)